# Multi-value attribute in OpenAM IdP

Tags: configuration, saml, saml-2.0, openam, forgerock

To replicate the potential production scenario of an IdP initiated SAML request, I'm trying to set up a local (docker-based) version of OpenAM to serve as an IdP for an application (an SP) that I am developing.

The application is written in Django and is reliant on its ability to resolve groups associated with the user whose identity is being asserted in the SAML response from this IdP.

Specifically, I'd like to receive the names of groups for each user in SAML response in the following format:

`<Attribute name="groups">
   <AttributeValue>groupOne</AttributeValue>
   <AttributeValue>groupTwo</AttributeValue>
   <AttributeValue>groupThree</AttributeValue>
   <AttributeValue>groupFour</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>`

Does OpenAM have an ability to create a multivalue attribute list like that and if so, could someone please point me to the documentation describing how it's done via it's IdP management console (or otherwise).

[image: <img src="https://ibb.co/bMsXR7" alt="Need a multivalued 'group' attribute" />]

And, by the way, I've attempted to ask the question on [OpenAM IdP Forum](https://forum.forgerock.com/forum/fr-projects/openidm/), however their system doesn't seem to accept new topics (I'm not seeing my question displayed there, after multiple attempts).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to use the IdentityManagement forum, which is not the same as IdP, but a Forgerock product to manage identities. Try to raise the question in the access management forum. Unfortunately, I am not firm with SAML usage on AM, so I can't offer you more help than that ;)

Comment: @jonasheinisch: Thank you for a pointer, I just tried posting on Access Management forum there as well with the same result - the post doesn't appear on the forum and despite the ever-increasing Leaderboard Score, the Forum tab lists no active postings and no topics started.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon Multivalued attributes are supported out of the box, AM will automatically create multiple AttributeValue XML elements for such attributes.

Comment: @PeterMajor Any pointers on how to pass the `groups` sting into that field - would that need to be a custom attribute mapper as you alluded to in that other question or is it also available (I couldn't find it) out of the box?  Appreciate if you could refer me to some docs / code on that topic.

Comment: I think custom attribute mapper is the way to go and use AMIdentity objects directly. https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/5.5/apidocs/com/sun/identity/idm/AMIdentity.html#getMemberships-com.sun.identity.idm.IdType- should be used with IdType.GROUP